# How to identify the name of the file which calls the function in python?

Tags: python

I have a server.py which contains a function and other files like requestor1.py requestor2.py .... requestorN.py

Server.py contains a function :

```
def callmeforhelp()
    return "I am here to help you out!"
```

and requestor1.py file calls the function callmeforhelp() and it has the imports needed to call the function from server.py

Is there a way my server.py knows which file is calling it?

Something similar like below :

When requestor1.py calls the function, then :

```
def callmeforhelp()
    print "Now I am being called by : "+caller // caller must contain the value as requestor1.py or even full path of requestor1.py
    return "I am here to help you out!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it in your `server` file:

```
import inspect

def callmeforhelp():
    result = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe(), 2)
    print("Caller is: " + str(result[1][1]))
```

Comment: Can this return the full file path?

Comment: @PrasathGovind: It will give you address. I've tried it with this sample and it works fine for me: `main.py, src/requester.py, src/sever.py`. `requester.py` will call a method of `server.py`. and `main.py` file is the main file which called `requester.py`. And I start it with: `python main.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to get at the caller's local attributes:

```
import sys

def callmeforhelp():
    print("Called from", sys._getframe(1).f_locals['__file__'])
```

This is a feature of CPython and is not guaranteed to be present in other language implementations.